# How do I make sprites overlap eachother based on a layering system?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

In Unity, I am building a 2D puzzle game, however I need to make sure that certain sprites are rendered on top of other sprites when they are above them.

Here is an example switch (left) and block (right).

[image: Switch on the left, block on the right.]

I wanted to make sure that the green block appears on top of the green switch when it passes over it, so how do I avoid a situation like this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SpriteRenderer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) has [Order in layer](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.html) inspector property which determines sprite draw order.

You can see how to use it in this tutorial video: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, turned out I was just ordering the layers in the opposite order to the way should have been.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does the job. If you want to organize the pieces that a certain kind appear on top of another kind, and you have a lot of pieces, take a look at [Sorting Layers](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers). If not, you learnt something new ;)